# Post method via Airtable API using a Google Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, urlfetch, airtable, http-status-code-422

I have the following code in a Google Script:

```
var data = {
    "records": [
          {
          "fields": {
              "Contract Address": "test",
              "0x8df3aad3a84da6b69a4da8aec3ea40d9091b2ac4": "1234"
          }
          }
    ]
};

var options = {
  "method" : "post",
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  // "payload" : data,
  "payload" : JSON.stringify(data)
};

function tryAPost(){
  var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Balance%20Tracking?api_key=keyxxxxxxxxxx";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //console.log(response.getContentText());
 console.log(response.getResponseCode());
};
```

I get the following response:

```
422
```

And the data does not end up in Airtable.

The payload works in the body of a post request in Postman.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT Per Comment:

here's the exmaple code from airtable:

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'}).base('xxxxxxxxxxxx');

base('Balance Tracking').create([
  {
    "fields": {
      "Contract Address": "Thu, 03 Feb 2022 15:12:37 GMT",
      "0xfecf784f48125ccb7d8855cdda7c5ed6b5024cb3": 12055358359168
```

Adding postman screenshot per comment:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide us some documentation as the api docs don't seem to be in the public. Try `"payload" : JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I added the example code from airtable to the question.  I tried ```JSON.strigify(data)``` and it didn't work.

Comment: It's JSON.stringify(object)

Comment: You need to at least show the postman screenshot. Also, you  should log the response as text: `console.log(response.getContentText())`

Comment: @Cooper I'm sorry to be so thick, but I thought ```data``` was an object.

Comment: @TheMaster I added ``` console.log(response.getContentText());``` and a screenshot from Postman.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: In postman, where is the `API_KEY` set? And could you update your script with `JSON.stringify(data)` and `console.log(response.getResponseCode())`

Comment: @TheMaster Updated per our comment. In Postman, the key is after Bearer in the Authorization.  Toward the bottom of the screenshot.

Comment: So try removing it from the url, `?api_key=xxxxx` in the url and send it as header here in urlfetch too.  contentType syntax is wrong as well.  `var options = {
  "method" : "post",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  "payload" : JSON.stringify(data), headers: {Authorization: \`Bearer xxxAPIKEYxxx\`}
};` Also try changing `"1234"` to `1234`, if the rest doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in the Airtable Forum and someone came up with a solution that worked.

Here's the [link](https://community.airtable.com/t/how-to-post-via-api-from-google-scripts/46210/5?u=david_weinstein).

Here's the answer:

```
//
// post to Airtable (universal)
//
function atPostTable_(baseKey, tableName, payload)
{
  var options = 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + cMyAirtableAPIKey,
          'Content-Type'  : 'application/json'
        },
        payload : JSON.stringify(payload),
        muteHttpExceptions : true,
        followRedirects: true
      };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cAirtableAPIEndpoint + baseKey + "/" + encodeURIComponent(tableName), options).getContentText();
  return(response);
}
```